# Flutter/PageView. Переключение по кнопке

Tags: flutter, dart

Всем привет.

И так, как заблочить свайп(скрол) в PageView разобрался. А вот как сделать так, чтобы смена происходила по нажатию кнопки от начала и до конца массива?

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  static final controller = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  List<Widget> array = [
    Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Yellow'),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Blue'),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Grey'),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Green'),
      ),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: PageView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: array,
                controller: controller,
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('NEXT'),
              onPressed: () {

              },
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У контроллера есть метод jumpToPage / nextPage /  animateToPage, ну или можете initialpage сделать в качестве переменной и менять её